# Printf unsigned hexadecimal from decimal in C

Tags: c, printf

So I've just started learning C this week and currently practising basic functions. There was a question that required me to print out a long int in hexadecimal, but the printout I got wasn't the same as the sample answer. Here's the code I wrote. Thanks heaps.

```
typedef struct database{
    long int organization;
} database;

int main() {
    struct database database = {-481};
    printf("%x", database.organization);
    return 0;
}
```

expected result: fffffffffffffe1f

result recieved: fffffe1f

Comment: You should enable more compiler warnigns. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. It should warn you about function argument mismatch. For `%x` an `unsigned int` is expected, not a `long int`.

Comment: Reread the chapter on format specifiers for `printf()`: You need to use `"%lx"`.

Comment: Another issue is that you seem to expect `long int` to have 64 bits. That is not defined by the standard. It could also be 32 bits.

Comment: Be careful, In C an int is at least 2 bytes, a long is at least 4 bytes, a long long is at least 8 bytes, a short is at least 1 byte. Just because we often assume an int is 4 bytes doesn't make it so, and just because other languages define long as 8 bytes doesn't make it so neither.

Comment: @Dmitry "a short is at least 1 byte." --> true, yet it is also at least 16-bits (e.g. 2 bytes).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica My bad, you're right, double checked this to be true in dos/turbo c, `sizeof(short)` is 2 bytes even there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long int` is non-portable and can have different sizes. Instead use portable types from `stdint.h` and in case of `printf` print them using `inttypes.h`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct database{
    uint64_t organization;
} database;

int main() {
    struct database database = {-481};
    printf("%"PRIX64, database.organization);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Saying "`long int` is non-portable" is a bit misleading.  Equally, the `+` operator is non-portable, as it can translate to different opcodes on different processors. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit If something boils down to 32 bit on some computers and 64 bits on other computers, it's pretty much the very definition of non-portable. C programmers need to care about the size and range of variables, they do not need to care about which op codes some operator translates to.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for all the help. Adding more compiler warnings helped me find out about function argument mismatch and hanging "%x" to "%lx" fixed it.

```
typedef struct database{
    long int organization;
} database;

int main() {
    struct database database = {-481};
    printf("%lx", database.organization);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edited it . It was supposed to be "%lx" instead of "%x" in line 7. My bad for the typo

Comment: `printf("%lx", database.organization);` with a negative `database.organization` is _undefined behavior_ (UB) - albeit, typically an acceptable UB.  `"%lx"` matches `unsigned long`.